# Parse Date to DatePicker that is declared in XAML on page that is defined by ContentView - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, parsing, xamarin.forms, parameter-passing

I have a 1st Page with a DatePicker. On Navigation, I want to pass the data from DatePicker to a DatePicker on Target Page.

The problem is that the Target Page is defined by ContentView that is not used from anywhere apart from the Target Page itself.

Here is the Original Page with first DatePicker:

```
    public TavoloList ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        DateTime currentDate = MainDatePicker.Date;
        this.BindingContext = new TavoloListViewModel(Navigation);
    }



    <DatePicker x:Name="MainDatePicker" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Here is the TavoloListViewModel part:

```
    public TavoloListViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;


        AddCommand = new Command(async () => await ShowAddTavolo());
    }
    async Task ShowAddTavolo()
    {
        await _navigation.PushAsync(new AddTavolo());
    }
```

Here is the AddTavolo in XAML:

```
<local:TavoloContentView />
```

Here is the TavoloContentView :

```
    <StackLayout Spacing="12">

    <DatePicker x:Name="pickArrivalDate" Date="{Binding Arrivo}"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="pickDepartureDate" Date="{Binding Partenza}"/>

</StackLayout>
```

I tried adding:

```
TavoloContentView.pickArrivalDate.Date = currentDate;
```

To the AddTavolo code behing part but I get error saying that TavoloContentView.pickArrivalDate is inaccessible due to its protection level. (Obviously I was also passing DateTime currentDate across whole route but I can arrive to AddTavolo page only. I don't know how to pass it further to the TavoloContentView)

I am posting AddTavoloViewModel:

```
    public AddTavoloViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
        _tavolo = new Tavolo();
        _tavoloRepository = new TavoloRepository();

        AddTavoloCommand = new Command(async () => await AddTavolo());
        ViewAllTavoloCommand = new Command(async () => await ShowTavoloList());
    }

    async Task AddTavolo()
    {

        bool isUserAccept = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Add Tavolo", "Do you want to save Tavolo details?", "OK", "Cancel");
        if (isUserAccept)
        {
            _tavoloRepository.InsertTavolo(_tavolo);
            await _navigation.PushAsync(new TavoloList());
        }
    }
```

And AddTavolo code behind:

```
    public AddTavolo()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new AddTavoloViewModel(Navigation);

    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: yes, I'm doing this now.

Comment: It is a page defined by TavoloContentView.

Comment: TavoloContentView is used only to define layout of AddTavolo Page.

Comment: AddTavolo Page uses binding.

Comment: As you can see in TavoloContentView xaml, there is DatePicker that uses binding to pass selected date to the DB via model.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not with data passing. I posted only the code with regards to the problem. Passing arguments between the pages.

Comment: I would normally pass argument between methods, but in this case, I cannot pass to TavoloContentView. I can arrive to AddTavolo only.

Comment: Add a costructor to AddTavolo with a parameter that holds the date you want to pass to it. -> public AddTavolo(DateTime date2pass){//}

Comment: However i think that you should use just viewmodel to pass the data. Without using the name of the controls of your view.

Comment: but, when using parameter as you wrote, I cannot access the AddTavolo's DatePicker to assign the parameter to it. That is the problem, since the DatePicker is defined in XAML TavoloContentView.

Comment: Infact you should use the viewmodel, set the date in the viewmodel and in the end bind this date to the datepicker.

Comment: But I would have to edit my model class that is used to store data in SQLite. The date I am pulling is not destined to be saved in SQLite.

Comment: your ViewModel and your data model are not necessarily the same thing

Comment: I create a new model just for the sake of that date I need to pass. I am creating the viewmodel for it now and then I will use it to pass data between pages. I'll see how it works.

Comment: however it's a lot of work to do simple argument passing,.